# How did this person who has 1 rep comment on a question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, new-users, convert-to-comment

So here is their [profile](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/users/1519/athena).

And here is the [question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/892/who-were-aphrodites-parents).

How did the person in question, who has 1 rep, comment on a question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This person posted an answer. A one liner which a moderator converted to a comment.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I forgot that I was the one that didn't flag it.... oops.

Comment: @Oded maybe add a visual indication in such a case, like the pencil icon for edited comment, so that people won't get baffled by this?

Comment: Seconding @Sha, this appears a LOT in per site metals.

Comment: @PhMgBr: Amusing typo, that; I'm pretty sure only Chem SE has per-site metals!

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think "Music Fans" has quite a few too.

Comment: @Nat I SWEAR it was the autocorrect.