# Add visual indication that a comment was originally posted as an answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, convert-to-comment

Inspired by [How did this person who has 1 rep comment on a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278931/how-did-this-person-who-has-1-rep-comment-on-a-question) and [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278931/how-did-this-person-who-has-1-rep-comment-on-a-question#comment903569_278933), I think that adding a visual indication when a comment was actually an answer that was converted to comment by a moderator or by the system will prevent confusion.

Using the existing design of edited comment, what I have in mind is also an icon to the right of the comment timestamp:

> [image]

With a tooltip like:

> this comment has been converted from existing answer

Same goes for comments on such an answer, that also gets converted to comments on the question.

I don't think we need link to the deleted answer, just this simple indicator.

Comment: If I see that icon beside a comment I might also think it indicates that "this comment might come off the screen and kill you so be careful what you're replying" so I'd say we implement it.

Comment: I think a tooltip would be better.

Comment: @Laurel only a tooltip? On what exactly? I do mention having a tooltip over the indicator.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What about on the timestamp?

Comment: @Laurel big no. First, the timestamp already showing a tooltip, of the exact date and time. Second, my whole point is visual indication. Only a tooltip is totally missing this point. Don't be afraid to downvote if you don't agree with visual indicator, that's what downvotes are for. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't disagree (except with your choice of icon). I just thought of something else: what if it used the edited pencil symbol? (It would say that a mod transformed it in the tooltip.)

Comment: Again a big "no", @Laurel - nobody will  bother to hover the pencil, it's already known and obvious it means "this comment was edited", and converting answer to comment does *not* count as an edit. (Moderator can edit any comment, but that's a totally different thing)

Comment: How useful is it to actually know that an answer has been converted? Just to avoid occasional confusion?

Comment: @David avoid confusion which leads to asking in meta sites, and another piece of information. If "useful" is the only thing that matters, we don't need the pencil icon for edited comment as well, since we can't really see the previous version, and we also won't need tons of other things all around SE.

Comment: May I suggest a different symbol, e.g. an arrow pointing *into* a speech bubble - the symbol you suggested generally means 'open in a new tab/window' or 'external link'

Comment: @angussidney yeah, good point... will try to look for such icon.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think one exists, they may have to design their own